# Resolution (?) changes when zooming in local scene ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, elevation, zoom, display, local-scene

I've made a polygon feature with varying Z-values on the different vertices. It's based on sea level changes in different areas, and I intend to display elevated shorelines in a larger region. The elevation information of the feature layer is set to "At an absolute height" based on geometry Z-values. However, when I zoom in or out in the local scene, the way the feature is displayed in relation to the underlying elevation surface changes. I guess there is a problem with scale and resolution, so that elevation information gets compressed when zooming out? Or is this the result of some other issue?

[image: Notice the piece of flat land (which is actually a lake) in the middle part of the island in the center of the map]

[image: Here this area has turned blue, which is the colour of my feature layer, when zoomed further out]

I've tried changing the "Antialiasing mode" under "Display" in "Options".
I've also tried turning off optimization of textures under "Display" in layer properties.
I've tried changing the elevation surface from the default "WorldElevation3D/Terrain3D" to a custom elevation surface based on a DEM.